# InputStream returns unexpected -1/empty

Tags: java

I seem to be hitting a constant unexpected end of my file. My file contains first a couple of strings, then byte data.

The file contains a few separated strings, which my code reads correctly.

However when I begin to read the bytes, it returns nothing. I am pretty sure it has to do with me using the Readers. Does the BufferedReader read the entire stream? If so, how can I solve this?

I have checked the file, and it does contain plenty of data after the strings.

```
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
String line;
{
    line = br.readLine();
    String split[] = line.split(" ");

    if (!split[0].equals("#binvox")) {
        ErrorHandler.log("Not a binvox file");
        return false;
    }
    ErrorHandler.log("Binvox version: " + split[1]);
}

ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int nRead, cnt = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];

while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    cnt += nRead;
}

buffer.flush();
// cnt is always 0
```

The binvox format is as followed:

```
#binvox 1
dim 64 40 32
translate -3 0 -2
scale 6.434
data
[byte data]
```

I'm basically trying to convert the following C code to Java:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/read_binvox.html

Comment: Does the file contain *binary* or *text* data after the `#binvox` marker?

Comment: I've added the binvox header format. Here is the C equivalent: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/read_binvox.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw someone else's code that solved exactly this.

He/she used *DataInputStream*, which can do a *readLine* (although deprecated) and *readByte*.

Answer (score 1):

For reading the whole `String` you should do this:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine();) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
```

and then you may do a cycle to split each line, or just do what you have to do during the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

As *icza* has alraedy wrote, you can't create a `InputStream` and a `BufferedReader` and user both. The `BufferedReader` will read from the `InputStream` as many as he wants, and then you can't access your data from the `InputStream`.

You have several ways to fix it:

1. Don't use any `Reader`. Read the bytes yourself from an `InputStream` and call `new String(bytes)` on it.

   Store your data encoded (e.g. Base64). Encoded data can be read from a `Reader`. I would recommend this solution. That'll look like that:

```
public byte[] readBytes (Reader in) throws IOException
{
    String base64 = in.readLine(); // Note that a Base64-representation never contains \n
    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
    return data
}
```

Comment: Can't I just get the char data and convert that to bytes?

Comment: @RobotRock This is exactly what I write there - with the exception that it is base64-encoded. If it isn't encoded (no matter how), you can't exchange files from different platforms as they'll have different encodings

Comment: I have no say in the specification of the file. What you do above is getting the string as base64 bytes. However I wonder, if I get the string as char array, if I can convert each char to byte.

Comment: @RobotRock Those char's are representated in bytes, that's correct, but nearly every OS uses another encoding (UTF-8, ISO-8859-15, ...) so it's more dificult to store your data there

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap an `InputStream` in a `BufferedReader` and use both.

As its name hints, `BufferedReader` might read ahead and buffer data from the underlying `InputStream` which then will not be available when reading from the underlying `InputStream` directly.

Suggested solution is not to mix text and binary data in one file. They should be stored in 2 separate files and then they can be read separately. If the remaining data is not binary, then you should not read them via `InputStream` but via your wrapper `BufferedReader` just as you read the first lines.

Comment: The problem is you're mixing text data and binary data in one file. You shouldn't do that. And if you don't, you can read them separately.

Comment: I didn't write the specification of the file however.

Comment: Whoever wrote it then most likely the remaining of the file is not binary but text as well. You should just proceed to read the rest with the same `BufferedReader` and not via the underlying `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a `BinvoxDetectorStream` that pre-reads some bytes

```
public class BinvoxDetectorStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream orig;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    private int buflen;
    private int bufpos = 0;


    public BinvoxDetectorStream(InputStream in) {
        this.orig = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        this.buflen = orig.read(this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.length);
    }

    public BinvoxInfo getBinvoxVersion() {
        // creating a reader for the buffered bytes, to read a line, and compare the header
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bais)));
        String line = rdr.readLine();
        String split[] = line.split(" ");
        if (split[0].equals("#binvox")) {
            BinvoxInfo info = new BinvoxInfo();
            info.version = split[1];
            split = rdr.readLine().split(" ");

            [... parse all properties ...]

            // seek for "data\r\n" in the buffered data
            while(!(bufpos>=6 &&
                    buffer[bufpos-6] == 'd' &&
                    buffer[bufpos-5] == 'a' && 
                    buffer[bufpos-4] == 't' && 
                    buffer[bufpos-3] == 'a' && 
                    buffer[bufpos-2] == '\r' && 
                    buffer[bufpos-1] == '\n') ) {
                bufpos++;
            }
            return info;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if(bufpos < buflen) {
             return buffer[bufpos++];
        }
        return orig.read();
    }
}
```

Then, you can detect the Binvox version without touching the original stream:

```
BinvoxDetectorStream bds = new BinvoxDetectorStream(in);
BinvoxInfo info = bds.getBinvoxInfo();
if (info == null) {
    return false;
}
...
[moving bytes in the usual way, but using bds!!! ]
```

This way we preserve the original bytes in `bds`, so we'll be able to copy it later.